# Show all recent git commits, whether they belong to a locally checked-out branch or not

Tags: git

Let's say I have a git repo with various branches.  If I do

```
git log --oneline | head
```

I will see a list of the latest commits on the current branch.  If I do

```
git log --branches=* --oneline | head
```

I will see a list of the latest commits on any locally checked-out branch.  But what should I do to see a list of all the latest commits, whether or not they are on any locally checked-out branch?  As far as I can tell, this isn't a matter of the commits only existing on the remote, because I can do e.g.

```
git checkout <hash>
```

and see the contents of the commit; it's just that if I then check out `master` again, I cannot get it to show up in `git log`.

Comment: Update: this is not strictly speaking an answer to my question, but I have solved the problem for my purposes (and perhaps others') by doing `git log --oneline --remotes=*` which I guess shows any commit belonging to a checked-out branch on a remote.

Comment: What's the problem with a simple `git log --oneline --all`?

Comment: Leave out `=*`, it either works to do nothing, or (in rare cases on Linux) causes problems. If you want a glob pattern, quote it (`="abc[d-g]*"`) to protect the `*`, `[`, and `?` characters from the command line interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `git log` starts with the currently checked out commit (called HEAD) and works back through its history from there.

I believe you want [`--all`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---all).

> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/, along with HEAD, are listed on the command line as .

So if you have branch1, branch2, origin/branch1, origin/branch2, tag1, tag2 `git log --all` is equivalent to `git log branch1 branch2 origin/branch1 origin/branch2 tag1 tag2 HEAD`.

If all you want to see is the commits in chronological order, that's enough. If you'd like to see how they relate add `--graph` to show their connections and `--decorate` to show references (tags and branches).